# Multi variable/feature Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

i want to categorize the height of person using multilayer keras, if the height more than 170 should return 1 whereas less than 170 return 0

```
data_input = [[0,165], [0,166], [0,167], [0,172], [0,173]]
data_output = [0,0,0,1,1]
model = keras.Sequential([
  keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(1,)),
  keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(data_input, data_output, epochs=5)
predictions = model.predict([0,184])
print(predictions)
```

but it gave me error "ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 2 input samples and 5 target samples."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should Use Numpy to wrap your input

```
data_input = np.array(data_input).reshape(5 ,2)
data_output = np.array(data_output).reshape(5)
```

by the way , why you use ML to calculate a simple condition classfy problem

Comment: actually i have far more complex problem,  but i want to use simpler case first to understand how multi layer work